# Typeahead which must be a single dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

I'm having a problem with the widget typeaheadbasic from yii2 framework ... I'm trying to show an array, but it says "You must set the property 'data' to typeahead to be a single dimensional array."
Do you know why this is not working?

The array returns this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "relva" [1]=> string(9) "alcatrão" }
```

Code:

```
$tipocampo=ArrayHelper::getColumn(TipoDeCampo::find()->all(), 'tipo');
 echo $form->field($model, 'Tipo_de_campo_idTipo_de_campo')->widget(TypeaheadBasic::className([
               'data' => $tipocampo,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => ['highlight'=>true],
    ]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see on the [GitHub Usage](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-typeahead#usage), your syntax is a bit off. It should be this:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'Tipo_de_campo_idTipo_de_campo')->widget(TypeaheadBasic::className(), [
           'data' => $tipocampo,
           'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],
           'pluginOptions' => ['highlight'=>true],
        ]
);
```

You were passing the array to the `className()` function, but it needed to be passed as the second argument of the `widget` function.